# md5sum using grub command line

Tags: grub

I'm new to grub and having issues doing some simple usage tests.

from the grub command line I run

```
insmod hashsum
```

I have several partitions mounted, we'll be using msdos2 for this example ...

```
md5sum -p ./msdos2
```

The command executes seemingly without error ... however I can't see the resulting hash.

I've tried several things including echo

```
echo md5sum -p ./msdos2
```

... but all I get is an error saying invalid parameter '-p'

So ... how can I run the md5sum and see the hash from the grub command line?

A little update: 
    md5sum (hd0, part1)/ gives me a non valid file, as its a folder. However, is there a way to run hashsums directly on a partition or do you have to use a .c file to create a .mod file that opens the device using (grub_device_open) then call hashsum on that?

Answer (score 0):

> ... but all I get is an error saying invalid parameter '-p'

`-p` isn't a valid parameter, just use `md5sum ./msdos2`

Comment: -p is a prefix for the base directory for hash list (from help md5sum) ... using your recommendation you get the error invalid file name ...